# PHPSpreadsheet --> How to delete a single image/drawing

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I use PHPSpreadsheet to open an Excel-Sheet and exchange an image in cell A27.
My actual code doesn't replace the image but add it as overlay to the existing image:

```
$inputFileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."output/test.xlsx";
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Remove old image --> Fails
$sheet->setCellValue("A27", "");
echo "Bild ".$pfad_bild." in Zelle ".$zelle." einfügen<br>";
$image_placer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$image_placer->setName("myimg");
$image_placer->setDescription("myimg");
$image_placer->setPath("path/to/new/image");
$image_placer->setHeight(500);
$image_placer->setCoordinates('A27');
$image_placer->setOffsetX(0);
$image_placer->setOffsetY(0);
$image_placer->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());

// Save file with new tmp-name
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($inputFileName."_");
// Delete old file  
unlink($inputFileName);
// Rename new file to correct name
rename($inputFileName."_", $inputFileName);
```

Does anyone has an idea how to delete the Image from the Cell?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer, i actually found out:

```
global $reader;
$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');

function exchange_image_within_cell($path_file,$cell,$path_img) {
    global $reader;
    $inputFileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path_file;
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

    $bilder_array=$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection();
    $bilder_array_copy = $bilder_array->getArrayCopy();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($bilder_array_copy as $drawing) {
        $coordinates=$drawing->getCoordinates();
        if ($coordinates==$cell) {
            // Delete Image from Array/Cell
            unset($bilder_array_copy[$i]);  
        }
        $i++;
    }
    // Reorder and exchange array
    $bilder_array_copy = array_values($bilder_array_copy);
    $bilder_array->exchangeArray($bilder_array_copy);

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    // Place new image
    $sheet->setCellValue($cell, "");
    $image_placer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
    $image_placer->setName($path_img);
    $image_placer->setDescription($path_img);
    $image_placer->setPath($path_img);
    $image_placer->setHeight(500);
    $image_placer->setCoordinates(''.$cell.'');
    $image_placer->setOffsetX(0);
    $image_placer->setOffsetY(0);
    $image_placer->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
    // Save file with new tmp-name;
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save($inputFileName."_");
    // Delete old file
    unlink($inputFileName);
    // Rename new file
    rename($inputFileName."_", $inputFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is correct, but is not brief at all. Basically, once you know the index `$i` of the drawing to be removed from the worksheet `$sheet`, you can use:

```
$drawings = $sheet->getDrawingCollection();
unset($drawings[$i]);
```